# how to create a new game like pacman, snake, airplane fight game in C# with xna

Tags: xna, c#

I have a school project to create a game develop in c#.. I know all Basic of OOP and c#. I don't know where to start?..

Suggestion will appreciated
Thank you

Comment: With a question this broad the best answer anyone can give you is: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

Comment: @dennmat It may be a bit broad but so far I think it has produced two questions with some useful information in it :)

Comment: These kinds of questions aren't good fits for the Q&A site format.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq  Feel free to take these questions to the chat once you reach enough reputation, though.

Answer (score 1):

The best suggestion I can give you, and the one I passed out while tutoring many people, is do not sit down and start to program an entire game. It always seems a bit daunting and flusters people into wasting their time.

My suggestion is to pick your overall game, and then make something in it.. The easiest example I can give you goes like this for the game Frogger.

- Make A Frog
- Make the frog move around the screen
- Make a car
- Make the car move around on its own in a set pattern
- Add in collision between the car and the frog
- Use the collision to detect when a frog reaches the other side of the board
- Add death tiles where the frog can not go using the collision as well
- Add in the logs that the frog can jump on that move in the death tiles
- Create new vehicles and add them to the cars.
- Create a randomly spawning fly and detect when you pick it up.
- Add in an action tracking system. Notably this would be used for a scoring mechanism, but if you are bored you could also use it for replays if you store what you track.

And I think that gets the general idea.. At the end you will come up with a game. The trick is to keep the set of tasks small.. The person I walked through this setup with went from thinking making a game impossible to having most of the above done in around 4-6 hours of work.. and actually produced a very amusing version of Frogger :)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup tutorials on http://create.msdn.com/en-US/
They have whole games with source code there, but all you need for games like snake is how to draw a texture on specific place and how to handle input.

For a snake

1. So i would suggest you to create a texture (an image) of one body part of a snake and find a way to display it. (Using **Content pipeline**, **ContentnManager.Load** and **SpriteBatch.Draw**)
2. Find out how to handle when someone presses keyboard and when he does move that body part and display it on next location (using **Keyboard.GetState()**)
3. Make moving of that body part automatical, and with keypress just change direction (using **Update** method on **Game1** class)
4. Draw other things like food
5. Find out how to handle collisions of snake and food (using **Rectangle** class and **Intersects** method)